# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have class that should initialize filter chain by itself

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

but still i get noSuchBeanDefinException.

My webSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

and here my AppInitialiser

```
public class WebAppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

i tried to use WebSecurityConfig.class in AppInit but then it shows An error that my service class that autowired in SecurityConfig doesn't initialised when AppInit Class works.
Also every single online example do like i do. They just use SecurityWebApplicationInitializer .

Comment: What happens when you annotate `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` with `@Component`?

Comment: nothing changes.

Comment: Have you enabled `@componentScan` for package your class is in?

Comment: my componentScan is set to whole project.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what you've been doing. I got the same error as you until I put WebSecurityContext into the classes returned in getRootConfigClasses(). When you did that was the error that the UserService wasn't found or was it that it couldn't work at that stage for some reason - e.g. a dependency on the database which was initialised afterwards?

Comment: yes. if i put it in the rootConfig i get an error. becouse UserSErvice bean doesn't exist yet when config classes initialise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - put WebSecurityConfig into

```
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class};
    }
```

and also add @componentScan package FOR EVERY CONFIG class you have. My mistake was that i thought that they know about each other. Guess not.